# Trying to create a thumbnail for a cloudkit share but

Tags: ios, swift, image, thumbnails, cloudkit

iOS 11.x Swift 4.2

Creating a cloudKit share and setting permissions on it. All looks good and it works, but for the thumbnail that I am getting the following error message which is beyond me. What is it saying?

> 2018-10-10 11:04:14.422093+0200 n2k Memo[12256:5302161]
>   [DocumentManager] Failed to associate thumbnails for picked URL
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/August2018/App/Icons/noun_Puzzle_787736.png
>   with the Inbox copy
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D13D04E1-8700-4B3E-AD0B-710D037B5253/tmp/ch.cqd.blah-Inbox/noun_Puzzle_787736.png:
>   Error Domain=QLThumbnail Code=2 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c444b070 {Error
>   Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Generation not found"
>   UserInfo={NSDescription=Generation not found}}}

My code looks like this ...

```
let share = CKShare(rootRecord: customRecord)
share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Marley" as CKRecordValue
share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.shareType] = "ch.cqd.blah" as CKRecordValue

let imageData = image2Save.pngData()!
let options = [
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 300] as CFDictionary
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
let imageReference = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options)!
let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: imageReference).pngData()
share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.thumbnailImageData] = thumbnail! as CKRecordValue
```

The image2Save is a valid UIImage that I subsequently display. Added code to show the thumbnail on screen. Thumbnail looks good.

Comment: have you found any solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Hi Amadeu. Yes I did get it work, but it was a while back. I'll try and fish out the code.